# default.a.map is not a function error in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently learning react. I wanted to import data from projectdata.js to app.js but react gave me this error

TypeError: _data_projectdata__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8___default.a.map is not a function

[image]

This the code written on app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './App.css';
import Projects from './components/Projects'
import ProjectBox from './components/ProjectBox'
import projectData from './data/projectdata'



function App() {
let data = projectData.map(function(item) 
{
  return (<ProjectBox key={item.id} project={item} />);
}
);
  return (
    <div className="outerwrapper">
      <div className="wrapper2">
        <Projects >
          {data}
         </Projects>

    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the code written on projectdata.js

```
const item = [
{ 
id : "1",
icon : "fas fa-bolt fa-8x",    
title : "Tesla Coil",
description : "something"
},
{
id : "2",
icon : "fas fa-microchip fa-8x", 
title : "Ardrino BT Car",
description : "Something",
},
{
id : "3",
icon : "fas fa-desktop fa-8x", 
title : "Unpacked",
description : "Something",
}
]
```

This the code written on ProjectBox.js

```
import React from 'react'

function ProjectBox(props){
    return(
<div>
    <i className={props.project.icon}></i>
<h1>{props.project.title}</h1>
<p>{props.project.description}</p>
</div>
    )
}
export default ProjectBox;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replace `const item = [` by `export default [`.

Explaination :

- when you import like `import a from './foo'`, what's in `foo.js` should be an `export default`.
- when you import like `import {a} from './foo'`, what's in `foo.js` should be a regular `export`.

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)